# Create Notification when my mobile it´s in a date

Tags: android, date, calendar, notifications

I´m trying to create a new Notification that will appear when a day has come.
For example: Today is 8 of September of 2014 and i want create a notification for tomorrow.

It´s like when your calendar reminds you something that you put a month ago

Could someone tell me how can i create a notification like the calendar when i´m in a specific day?

Thank a lot.

**EDIT**

Thanks you for all the answers, i found a tutorial of AlarmManager and it worked as you all said.

Comment: what you had tried for this.? there are many samples and answers related to this question.

Comment: try using `AlarmManager`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using AlarmManager in android
The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have your application code run at a specific time, even if your application is not currently running. For normal timing operations (ticks, timeouts, etc) it is easier and much more efficient to use Handler.

please refer this 
https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html